Playwright test failed to click on the search button on the page
In my playwright tests, failed to click on the search button even though I have added the wait. If we remove the selectParentClassificationByText(), selectClassificationByText() and typeWhereBoxField() test will click on the search button without any issue.
How can we fix this issue, could someone please advise ?
class SearchBoxPage {

    constructor(page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.searchBtnLocator = 'button[data-automation="searchButton"]';
    }

    async getSearchButton() {
        await this.page.click(this.searchBtnLocator); // Click the search button
    }

}

module.exports = SearchBoxPage;

// jobSearch.spec.js
 test('Type playwright, select Testing & QA and choose All Brisbane in the search page', async ({ page }) => {
    const searchPage = new SearchBoxPage(page);
    const browser = await chromium.launch({ 
      headless: true
     });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await searchPage.typeSearchQuery("cypress");
    await searchPage.clickClassificationField();
    await searchPage.selectParentClassificationByText("Information & Communication Technology");
    await searchPage.selectClassificationByText("Testing & Quality Assurance");
    await searchPage.typeWhereBoxField("All Brisbane QLD");
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
    await page.waitForSelector('button[data-automation="searchButton"]');
    await searchPage.getSearchButton();
    const totalCount = await searchPage.getJobsCountHeader();
    console.log("What is the count we getting::"+totalCount);
    const totalCountValue = parseInt(totalCount);
    expect(totalCountValue).toBeGreaterThan(10);
    await page.close();
  });

error:
 at pageObjects\searchBoxPage.js:61

  59 |
  60 |     async getSearchButton() {
> 61 |         await this.page.click(this.searchBtnLocator); // Click the search button
     |                         ^
  62 |     }
  63 |
  64 |

    at SearchBoxPage.getSearchButton (C:\work\realestate\tests\pageObjects\searchBoxPage.js:61:25)
    at C:\work\realestate\tests\jobSearch.spec.js:39:22

Test repo:
https://github.com/scrumvisualize/realestate

Please share a [mcve] including all of your helpers and the site you're automating. Note that you don't need to call await chromium.launch, page = await browser.newPage(); and page.close() at the end of your test. Use {page} in the test callback argument and Playwright will do that for you. I'd also use a web first assertion for the price. Avoid CSS selectors in tests, and don't use timeouts.

Thank you, will provide repo details soon

Thanks, although it should be in the question itself and minimal (no extra code that doesn't contribute to the bug).

Yes adding a minimal example is good , Other than repo May I ask how  can I provide minimal example of framework ?

You can share the repo too, but it's not exactly optimal or a substitute for a MRE. Making a minimal example takes time but the link up top has 2 strategies: (1) rebuild from the ground up until you have a miniature app and test suite that reproduces the problematic behavior without any distractions or (2) strip out parts of the code and tests until the problem disappears, then re-add the last part back in, and remove any other unnecessary parts until it's minimized, again removing distractions. Often, you'll figure out the problem yourself doing this exercise, and it's usually what I'd do.

Thank you, I have added the repo details to the last part in question

While working wit reactjs project I could create a codesandbox link to share a minimal example. For this one I am not sure, I can give all page related functions and baseurl in the test may be other than repo ?

Try setting up searchPage after you have the actual page.
    const browser = await chromium.launch({ 
      headless: true
     });
    const newPage = await browser.newPage();
    const searchPage = new SearchBoxPage(newPage);

It's still not clear why you use 2 pages, but maybe
